# Number of players on a team (graph theory)

Tags: graph-theory

You have two teams, $a$ and $b$, whose players are on the same graph. Players from team $a$ are adjacent to 3 other players and players from team $b$ are adjacent to 1 other player.

Players can be adjacent to each other even if they are not on the same team. There exists 1 unique path between any two players (regardless of team). Prove that if team $a$ has $x$ players, then team $b$ has $x-2$ players.

I have no idea how to approach this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is $x-2$ a typo for $x+2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need one more assumption, which you did not state. Namely, I think you have to assume that every vertex of the graph is on team A or team B.

Let $x$ be the number of players on team A, and $y$ the number of players on team B. Let $e$ be the number of edges in the graph.

The condition "there is a unique path between any two vertices" means that the graph is a tree. It is a basic fact about trees that the number of edges is one less than the number of vertices, so we get the equation
$$e=x+y-1\tag1$$
By the "handshake lemma", the sum of the degrees of the vertices is twice the number of edges, so we get another equation:
$$3x+y=2e\tag2$$
Eliminating $e$ between the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get the equation
$$3x+y=2(x+y-1)\tag3$$
which simplifies to
$$x+2=y\tag4$$
Oops, you wanted $y=x-2$? But I think my answer is right; you could have just one player on team A, who is adjacent to each of the three players on team B.

Comment: Thank you so much